# Comparing algorithmic performance to old methods

Tags: performance, algorithm, comparison

I have written a new algorithm for something. Now I need to compare it with existing methods, some of which are old about 10 years.

The idea I had is to look at benchmarks of different processors over the years in order to establish how much faster my processor (i7-920) is than average processor from 2003. Then I would simply divide old methods' execution time by the speedup factor and use those numbers to compare with my own algorithm.

1. Has something like this been done? So I don't redo the existing work.
2. Can such a comparison be done some other way?
3. Are there some scientific papers written about such comparisons which I can reference?

Comment: Yes, I've done that for a university assigment once, but it didn't feel very fair :) The best approach is to run various implementations on the same processor.

Comment: @larsmans When did you do it? If it was recently maybe I could re-use your results (if you are willing to make it available). And dividing their time by this factor is more fair than just citing their self-reported time!

Comment: A few years ago. I predicted a speedup factor based on Moore's Law and the type of hardware reported in an paper from a few years back, then proved that even with that speedup in place, my algorithm was orders of magnitude faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know which of these are possible for you, but here's a list of options I can think of:

1. Run their implementation side-by-side on your machine against yours.
   This is the best option.
2. Rewrite their implementations and do (1).
   You preferably need to compare it against their test to ensure you get vaguely similar results.
3. Find a library that implements their algorithm (or multiple libraries) and do (1).
   I suggest multiple libraries, if possible, since a single one may not have implemented the algorithm efficiently. You may also want to compare these against their test.
4. Compare the algorithms mathematically.
   This may be difficult, but it's not impossible.
5. Do what you presented.
   (a) I would not recommend this as there are other determining factors in your computer other than the processor speed that affect the speed of an algorithm. Getting an equation that perfectly balances these will likely be very difficult.
   (b) There is a massive difference between top and bottom of the line computers, so using the average is not a particularly good idea. If the author didn't provide details regarding this, I'm afraid your benchmark is not likely to be too accurate.
6. Go out and buy a machine of similar specs to the one used by the desired test to benchmark on.
   A 10-year-old machine should be pretty cheap, if you can find one. Also, see (5.b).
7. Contact the author to allow for any of the other options.
   Papers often provide contact details of the authors, or you should be able to find them elsewhere if they have any sort of online presence and you're half-decent at using Google.

Answer (score 1):

If I were reviewing your results, I would be annoyed if you attempted to demonstrate less than an order of magnitude speedup this way. There are a lot of variables determining algorithm performance, and I would be skeptical that a generic benchmark could capture the right ones. My gold standard is old and new algorithms implemented by the same programmer, with similar effort made to optimize, running on the same hardware. Using the previous authors' implementation instead of making a new one is commonplace in the experimental algorithms literature, but using different hardware isn't.

Comment: Unfortunately, none of the previous authors makes their implementation available. Otherwise this problem would not have occurred.

Comment: @Dženan Write to them, then.

Answer (score 0):

Algorithmic performance is usually measured in big-O terms, for which it is better to count basic operations, like comparisons, and do it for a range of input sizes.

If you must measure overall time, at least eliminate other sources of difference.
As @larsmans said, do it on the same processor.

Also, if there is existing work, there's no harm in repeating it.
Generally, in science, that's a *good* thing.

Comment: For any non-trivial algorithm, it is not easy to determine big-O complexity. And even if that is possible, factors that go along with the main term can have decisive impact on comparison.

Comment: @Dženan: I guess what I was trying to say is pick something representing the input size and call it N. Then time your alg. with N=10, 100, 1000, and see if you can see the shape of the big-O curve. Then, if necessary, do the same with the competition. That way, you're not confusing the issue with constant factors, which can differ by orders of magnitude just by doing performance tuning without changing the algorithm.

Answer (score 0):

You should attempt to reduce the amount of differing factors between the two runs. I think just run-timing the two algorithms side by side on the same machine and/or comparing their Big O times are both equally valid and important. You should also attempt to use updated libraries and other external functions; using outdated ones my also be the cause of timing results.